# In LibreOffice Calc, how can I control whether the column or row is incremented when pasting?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In my LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet, I have a column in one sheet where I want to reference values from another sheet. I want to copy one cell, paste into multiple cells, and have it correctly set the references.

Let's say I start by coping a cell containing `=sheet2.A1`. **By default**:

- If I paste it into cells in the same **column**, it will increment the **row numbers**, like:

  ```
  =sheet2:A2
  =sheet2:A3
  ```
- If I paste it into cells in the same **row**, it will increment the **column names**, like this:

  ```
  =sheet2:B1   =sheet2:C1    =sheet2:D1
  ```

What I want is to **control** whether it increments the cell or column, so that I can paste into the same column and increment the column names, like this:

```
COLUMN A
=sheet2:A1
=sheet2:B1
=sheet2:C1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to copy a row of cells (A1:C1) and past them into another spread sheet in a way that changes the orientation from horizontal to vertical, in other words, pasting a row of cells into a column of cells.

Lucky day, this is simply solved by clicking on "Paste Special" and checking the box (lower left of the "Paste Special" window under "Options") next to "Transpose".  This will paste the copied cells into the opposite orientation.